# A list of all the miracles associated with the Man (Manna)

Tags: sources-mekorot, miracle, mon-manna

The Ibn Ezra on Sh'mot 16:35 [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.16.35?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)

> נסים רבים היו במן

I know of some of the many miracles associated with the mon but **is there a complete list anywhere with citations and sources**?

So far here are what I know based on what I have read and heard (from text, [lists](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10366-manna), medrash and word of mouth, though I don't have sources for each or know that each is authoritative/supported):

- the falling of the mon in general
- that it could taste like whatever the eater wanted it to
- it was absorbed completely in the body leading to no bodily waste
- it fell closer to the camp for righteous people
- Yehoshua's fell near Moshe
- it was not visible on Shabbat though it fell
- no matter how much anyone collected, it became 1 omer
- 1 omer became the amount each person needed
- it evaporated by mid day
- the amount collected on Friday became 2 omers
- the extra turned rancid by the next day except the doubled portion on Fridays
- the mon stayed in the Ark and didn't run rancid
- the mon collected right before Moshe's death stayed good for the 40 or so days until people made bread in Canaan
- it stopped at Moshe's death

Comment: Yoma 75 has a bunch

Answer (score -1):

Here's one for you that I didn't see anybody mentioning because of their lack of "scientifical" knowledge.

The Man that was not finished:

> "וְלֹא־שָׁמְעוּ אֶל־מֹשֶׁה וַיּוֹתִרוּ אֲנָשִׁים מִמֶּנּוּ עַד־בֹּקֶר **וַיָּרֻם תּוֹלָעִים וַיִּבְאַשׁ** ...׃
>
> But they paid no attention to Moses; some of them left of it until morning, and **it became infested with maggots** and stank."

The catch is that their belief was that the maggots and lice come into being spontaneously (it's Gemmorah elsewhere), so it is natural for Man (that is pure edible light, of course) to be infested with self-emerging slugs. So nobody counted it as a miracle, but I do.