# Clarification on the Mann scattering pattern

Tags: commentaries, beshalach, miracle, mon-manna

Following [the question on the Mann miracles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98411/a-list-of-all-the-miracles-associated-with-the-man-manna/) I would like to understand one specific miracle: how exactly did Mann fall closer to the righteous for them than for the wicked:

- Did it have name tags attached?
- Could Mann be stolen? Why couldn't the wicked take the closest Mann possible?
- Did it fall on everyone's private property? What about falling outside the camp for the wicked?
- How did everyone know where to look for his Mann? Did Moses tell each one his spiritual level?